# Expand nested dict within Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to reformat my nested dictionary before outputting it into csv.
My nested dictionary:

```
review = {'Q1': {'Question': 'question wording','Answer': {'Part 1': 'Answer part one', 'Part 2': 'Answer part 2'} ,'Proof': {'Part 1': 'The proof part one', 'Part 2': 'The proof part 2'}},
      'Q2': {'Question': 'question wording','Answer': {'Part 1': 'Answer part one', 'Part 2': 'Answer part 2'} ,'Proof': {'Part 1': 'The proof part one', 'Part 2': 'The proof part 2'}}}
```

So far I have tried:

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame(review)
my_df = my_df.unstack()
```

and get part way:

```
Q1  Answer      {'Part 1': 'Answer part one', 'Part 2': 'Answe...
    Proof       {'Part 1': 'The proof part one', 'Part 2': 'Th...
    Question                                     question wording
Q2  Answer      {'Part 1': 'Answer part one', 'Part 2': 'Answe...
    Proof       {'Part 1': 'The proof part one', 'Part 2': 'Th...
    Question                                     question wording
```

but I want it to look like this in the end:

```
Index   Question                Answer          Proof
Q1      question one wording    Answer part 1   Proof part 1
Q1      question one wording    Answer part 2   Proof part 2
Q2      question two wording    Answer part 1   Proof part 1
Q2      question two wording    Answer part 2   Proof part 2
```

So I need to melt/unstack/pivot/expand/other_manipulation_word the nested dictionary in the Dataframe.

I have looked at this for guidance but can't apply it to my own:
[Expand pandas dataframe column of dict into dataframe columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54344114/expand-pandas-dataframe-column-of-dict-into-dataframe-columns)

Comment: I'm not sure how to get the exact layout you want, but df.reset_index will achieve the desired effect on the index column.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one potential solution:

1) Create the initial `DataFrame` with orient 'index'

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(review, orient='index')
```

2) Create the shape of the final `DataFrame` using [`Index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html), [`Series.str.len`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) and [`DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

```
df_new = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.Answer.str.len())]
```

3) Fix 'Answer' and 'Proof' columns by passing to `DataFrame` contructor and using `stack` values

```
df_new['Answer'] = pd.DataFrame(df.Answer.tolist()).stack().values
df_new['Proof'] = pd.DataFrame(df.Proof.tolist()).stack().values
print(df_new)

            Question           Answer               Proof
Q1  question wording  Answer part one  The proof part one
Q1  question wording    Answer part 2    The proof part 2
Q2  question wording  Answer part one  The proof part one
Q2  question wording    Answer part 2    The proof part 2
```

Comment: Is to_list() a function from Pandas?
I don't see it here:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html
and I get an error:
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_list'

Comment: see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_list.html

Comment: you may be using an older version of pandas...? try `tolist()` without the underscore?

Comment: This works well but I'm surprised there isn't a method without forcing it. I can get the correct format with just one question i.e. Q1, doing:
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(review['Q1'])
print(df.T.unstack())